# Don't change <a> color on hover if there is active class

Tags: html, css, colors

Here is my **HTML** and **CSS** codes:

```css
ul {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 0;
  color: gray;
}
a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> <a> one </a> 
  </li>
  <li> <a class="active"> two </a> 
  </li>
  <li> <a> three </a> 
  </li>
```

I want to keep *current color* remain constant (always `red`, even for `hover`) where there is `active` class. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use: `.active:hover { color: red; }`.

```css
ul {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 0;
  color: gray;
}
a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
.active {
  color: red;
}
/* add this part */
.active:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> <a> one </a> 
  </li>
  <li> <a class="active"> two </a> 
  </li>
  <li> <a> three </a> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways:

First is simply add a hover rule for `.active` indicates red color:

```
.active:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

The second way is to exclude `.active` when hover using `:not` selector:

```
a:not(.active):hover {
    color: #000;
}
```

```css
l {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 0;
  color: gray;
}
a:not(.active):hover {
    color: #000;
}
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> <a> one </a> 
  </li>
  <li> <a class="active"> two </a> 
  </li>
  <li> <a> three </a> 
  </li>
```